# What is the function that allows you to avoid explicitly naming the dataset when using a variable in R?

Tags: r

I know there is a function for this and have used it in the past but can't seem to remember or find it.

basically I'm trying to do the following:

> data(mtcars)
>
> missing_function(mtcars)
>
> lm(mpg ~ cyl)

where "missing_function()" allows me to use the the variables in the mtcars dataset without having to use the "$".  For example:  "mpg" instead of "mtcars$mpg".

Comment: Use `with` or `transform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though generally frowned upon, `attach` will do that for you

```
R> attach(mtcars)
R> mpg
 [1] 21 21 23 21 19 18 14 24 23 19 18 16 17 15 10 10 15 32 30 34 22 16 15 13 19 27 26 30
[29] 16 20 15 21
R>
```

Comment: Note that `detach()` will remove the data from the environment too.